# Pandas - rolling mean with groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to Pandas.
I have a dataframe where I'm looking at Horse results.
I'm trying to get a rolling mean for position finished results in a column for the last 30 days for each horse. Here's an example of two horses from the dataframe:

```
        Horse            Position  OR   RaceDate    Weight
125283  cookie ring             4  59.0 2016-04-25  52.272727
126134  a boy named sue         7  46.0 2016-05-31  54.090909
137654  a boy named sue         4  49.0 2017-01-25  57.727273
138434  a boy named sue         8  48.0 2017-02-04  55.909091
138865  a boy named sue         2  48.0 2017-02-10  51.363636
140720  a boy named sue         3  50.0 2017-03-10  54.545455
141387  a boy named sue         7  49.0 2017-03-22  59.545455
143850  cookie ring             11  54.0 2017-05-25 56.818182
144203  cookie ring             9  54.0 2017-06-03  50.000000
```

So I need to groupby each horse and then apply a rolling mean for 90 days. Which I'm doing by calling the following:

```
df['PositionAv90D'] = df.set_index('RaceDate').groupby('Horse').rolling("90d")['Position'].mean().reset_index()
```

But that is returning a data frame with 3 columns and is still indexed to the Horse. Example here:

```
0          a b celebration 2011-08-24       3.000000
1          a b celebration 2011-09-15       4.500000
2          a b celebration 2012-05-29       4.000000
3        a beautiful dream 2016-10-21       2.333333
4        a big sky brewing 2008-04-11       2.000000
5        a big sky brewing 2008-07-08       7.500000
6        a big sky brewing 2008-08-11      10.000000
7        a big sky brewing 2008-09-20       9.000000
8        a big sky brewing 2008-12-30       4.333333
9        a big sky brewing 2009-01-21       3.666667
10       a big sky brewing 2009-02-20       3.777778
```

I need a column that is indexed the same as my original dataframe.

Can you help?

Comment: What are you expecting? Also, it would be more helpful if your example data matched. Try getting a small sample of your dataframe and perform your calculation on that small sample.

Answer (score 8):

Using `set_index()` will delete the original index, so use `reset_index()` first which will create a new column called 'index' containing your original index. Then inset of reset_index() at the end (which just creates an index 0, 1, 2...etc) use `set_index('index')` to go back to the original

So if you do the following, I think it will work:

```
df['PositionAv90D'] = df.reset_index().set_index('RaceDate').groupby('Horse').rolling("90d")['Position'].mean().set_index('index')
```

A simple data sample would be good to test it against, its a bit difficult to recreate from what you have given

**EDIT 1:**

Since you're switching indexes it's easier to split up a bit, see below, I've created some sample data which I think is similar to what you're getting at:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'foo': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
                   'bar': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
                   'baz': [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]},
                  index = [14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22])

df.reset_index(inplace=True)    # This gives us index 0,1,2... and a new col 'index'
df.set_index('baz', inplace=True)    # Replace with date in yours
# This next bit does the groupby and rolling, which will give a df 
# with a multi index of foo and baz, then reset_index(0) to remove the foo index level
# so that it matches the original df index so that you can add it as a new column
df['roll'] = df.groupby('foo')['bar'].rolling(3).sum().reset_index(0,drop=True)
df.reset_index(inplace=True)    # brings baz back into the df as a column
df.set_index('index', inplace=True)   # sets the index back to the original
```

This will give you a new column in the original df with the rolling values. In my example you will have `NaN` for the first 2 values in each group, since the window only starts at idx = window size. So in your case the first 89 days in each group will be `NaN`. You might need to add an additional step to select only the last 30 days from the resulting DataFrame

Comment: Actually this won't work, as when you do `rolling("90d")['Position']` you are selecting only the position column in each group, so you only get back the index, the group column and Position column, hence why you only see 3 returned (since you have done `reset_index()` there is an extra for the new index)

Comment: Have added an update to keep the original columns in the resulting data frame

Comment: This is a hidden gem: "Using set_index() will delete the original index"